# Collatz Sequence Program won't stop running/won't work

Tags: python, collatz

https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

I have a program that counts the length of the collatz sequence for each number.
I have tried using smaller numbers to see if it is because my program is too slow but even then the program never stops. Why? I can only think that my while loop never stops, but it should given the problem. Thanks.

```py
count = 0
count1 = 0
for n in range(2,10):
    count = 0
    j = n
    while j != 1:
        if j%2 == 0:
            j = j/2
        if j%2 != 0:
            j = 3*j+1
        count += 1
    if count > count1:
        count1 = count
print (count1)
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to become familiar with your debugger. Try to see if your IDE has a debugger and set some breakpoints. It will let you 'pause' your code and give you a look at what variables are at each step.         **Spoiler**: Change your 2nd `if` to `elif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from the pairs of `if` in the `while` loop:

```
while j != 1:
    if j%2 == 0:
        j = j/2
    if j%2 != 0:
        j = 3*j+1
```

As it is written, the condition is never realised. The only way for `j` to reach the value `1` is through the first `if`, but the second `if` (since `1` is odd) immediately increases it to `4`, creating an endless loop.

An `else` would do the trick:

```
while j != 1:
    if j % 2 == 0:
        j = j / 2
    else:
        j = 3 * j + 1

    count += 1
```